# Teamcity custom reports tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, teamcity, code-coverage

I am trying to create a custom tab in my Build reports. I followed this [link](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results) given under teamcity manual. But the tab simply does not appear for me. What am I doing wrong?

I see an entry being created in the config/main-config.xml like this. But still this does not help me showing the specific tab.

```
<report-tab title="Koverage" basePath="/usr/braga/helloworld" startPage="braga.html" />
```

[image]

By the way, I am trying to integrate the .html generated for rcov code coverage gme within my Rails project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out what I was doing wrong. Actually, I have to first create artifacts and have them saved in the artifact directory. Then, I will have to include those artifacts in the build I choose. The base path has be "." (meaning current directory) and the filename can be index.html. Here is a screenshot after I configured it.

[image: Screenshot]